# Facebook Instant Games - Playing Games with a Group of Players

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-instant-games

Some questions for sharing and playing together with friends:

1) How can I play a game with a Facebook group?

2) Can I post an update or an invite to a group?

3) I want to have a button in the game to share the game. Where I then can select to share on timeline, friends timeline, group, ... (like the normale share dialog).
But when I use shareAsync() I don't get the option to select where to share to.
How can I share the game to other people's timeline, chats and groups?

4) Can I directly create a context with multiple players?
Is there a way to call createAsync() with more then one playerId?
From an existing chat with multiple users I can already get a context with multiple players. But is it possible to create a multiplayer session from inside the game?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

1) If you share a post to a Facebook group you will be able to play there. The context type will be `POST`. We are working on bringing custom updates to Facebook posts. (I assume you mean Facebook group rather than Messenger group chat here).

2) We are working on bringing `updateAsync` updates to Facebook posts, although the updates will be posted to posts rather than the entire group. (Again, I assume you mean Facebook group rather than Messenger group chat here).

3) `shareAsync` is implemented differently depending on which surface you're playing on. If you're playing on Facebook.com, `shareAsync` will give you a regular Facebook share dialog. If you're playing in Messenger `shareAsync` is more targeted to the Messenger experience.

4) Instant Games does not currently support creating a context with multiple participants using `createAsync`. You can use `chooseAsync` along with the `minSize` and `maxSize` parameters to encourage players to choose an existing Messenger thread.

Comment: Thanks Chris!
Yes, I meant Facebook groups.
3) When I use shareAsync() on the web, I do not get the option in the share dialog to share to friend's timeline, group or message.
https://scontent-frx5-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/30442955_10209311826592493_5358321346457632768_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=779fc1c3f7d9b1fca65c16c6f8d573c3&oe=5B6B945F
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10209311826552492&set=gm.778645475664947&type=3&theater&ifg=1

Comment: The documentation regarding shareAsync is a bit different from what is mentioned here - can you clarify that the Messenger app on all devices will only allow sharing within Messenger? Is there no way for a mobile instant game to share a score or other achievement on a user's timeline at present?